# how to make for loop wait for a function to execute in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a for loop which invokes a function with loop variable as the paramter. i need the for loop to wait until the first invocation is executed, before the next

```
for(i=1;i<6;i++){
 demo($firstFrame,i)
}
```

how do we make the for loop wait.

The demo function has a timeout in it there for obviously the for loop will have to wait before invoking the function for the second time.

Comment: You can use a callback function

Comment: could you elaborate..?

Comment: Pls check this link http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027392/making-a-function-to-wait-an-event-before-returning Does this help you?
I suggest you to write your logic behind posting only single for-loop here. Some expert of stackoverflow may have better way to solve this problem instated of waiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     var demo = function(name, index, onCompleteFunc){
         /**do staff**/
         onCompleteFunc();// exec this func when you are done.
     }; 

     var iterator = function(iteration){
         if(iteration >= 0){
             demo($firstFrame, iteration, function(){
                        iterator(iteration-1);
             });
         }  
     }

     iterator(5);//this function start recurcively execute demo with indexes from 5 to 0
```

Answer (score 1):

use recurcive function;

```
demo($firstFrame,1)

function demo(firstFrame,i){
    if(i<6){
       //do something
       i++;
       setTimeout(function(){
          demo(firstFrame,i);
       },1000)
    }
}
```